# Connecting SQL Database from NodeJs - ConnectionError: Connection not yet open

Tags: sql, node.js

I am trying to connect SQL database from NodeJs, but getting this error:
**Error while querying database :- ConnectionError: Connection not yet open.**

```
 var executeQuery = function(res, query) { 
   var conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbConfig);

   conn.connect().then(function () {
     // create Request object
     var request = new sql.Request(conn);
     // query to the database
     request.query(query, function (err, queryResult) {
       if (err) {
         console.log("Error while querying database :- " + err);
         res.send(err);
       } else {
         res.send(queryResult);
       }
     });

     conn.close();
   })
}
```

Please help.

Thank You
James

Comment: Can you include your require statement `sql = require("...?!?");`?

Comment: @kumbhanibhavesh the error i get is ConnectionError: Connection not yet open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [connection pool](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql#connection-pools) class will return a promise, which resolves with the pool that was initiated by your connection :

```
 var executeQuery = function(res, query) { 

     var conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbConfig);

     conn.connect()
         .then(function (pool) {
             //    ^ the pool that is created and should be used

             // create Request object
             var request = new sql.Request(pool);
             //                            ^ the pool from the promise

             // query to the database
             request.query(query, function (err, queryResult) {
                 if (err) {
                     console.log("Error while querying database :- " + err);
                     res.send(err);
                 } else {
                     res.send(queryResult);
                 }
             });
             conn.close();
        });           
}
```

In your case `conn` variable is always the promise and not the connection itself.

A basic example of a connection pool from the documentation is as follows :

```
new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect().then(pool => {
    return pool.query`select * from mytable where id = ${value}`
}).then(result => {
    console.dir(result)
}).catch(err => {
    // ... error checks
})
```

Comment: @drichev Hi Can you please elaborate?
My require statement is : **sql = require("mssql");**
You mean , I should be creating a DB pool?
Could you please show that for me?

Comment: Well as far as what you pasted you want to create a connection pool and use it to make the query and the request. There are two ways to make it. 1 with a Promise and 2 with a callback. When you use it with a Promise ( no callback function provided ) you actually need to take what the promise resolved result is as your `pool` variable.

Comment: If possible could you please edit the same in my code to show the same? I am new to this, so not able tp grasp much.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: thanks @drichev... but I am still getting the error like : **ConnectionError: Connection not yet open.**
Mycurrent code is like exatly like your answer above. 
Kindly do help